# Webpack hot reloading ENOENT no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm working with Ubuntu on Windows. I cloned a fresh [react-redux-starter-kit](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit).
There is the same problem with [react-redux-universal-hot-example](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/) and with my own implementations.

After `npm install` I started the server with `npm start` and the page worked perfectly.

As soon as I edit a file I get the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mnt/c/Users/xxx/WebstormProjects/react-redux-starter-kit/src/main.js'
  at Error (native)
  at Compiler.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/xxx/WebstormProjects/react-redux-starter-kit/build/webpack.config.js:69:15)
  at Compiler.applyPlugins (/mnt/c/Users/xxx/WebstormProjects/react-redux-starter-kit/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:26:37)
  at Watching._done (/mnt/c/Users/xxx/WebstormProjects/react-redux-starter-kit/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:78:17)
  at Watching.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/xxx/WebstormProjects/react-redux-starter-kit/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:51:17)
  at /mnt/c/Users/xxx/WebstormProjects/react-redux-starter-kit/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:403:12
  at Compiler.next (/mnt/c/Users/xxx/WebstormProjects/react-redux-starter-kit/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:67:11)
  at Compiler.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/xxx/WebstormProjects/react-redux-starter-kit/node_modules/webpack/lib/CachePlugin.js:40:4)
  at Compiler.applyPluginsAsync (/mnt/c/Users/xxx/WebstormProjects/react-redux-starter-kit/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:71:13)
  at Compiler.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/xxx/WebstormProjects/react-redux-starter-kit/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:400:9)
  at Compilation.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/xxx/WebstormProjects/react-redux-starter-kit/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:577:13)
  at Compilation.applyPluginsAsync (/mnt/c/Users/xxx/WebstormProjects/react-redux-starter-kit/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:60:69)
  at Compilation.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/xxx/WebstormProjects/react-redux-starter-kit/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:572:10)
  at Compilation.applyPluginsAsync (/mnt/c/Users/xxx/WebstormProjects/react-redux-starter-kit/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:60:69)
  at Compilation.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/xxx/WebstormProjects/react-redux-starter-kit/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:567:9)
  at Compilation.applyPluginsAsync (/mnt/c/Users/xxx/WebstormProjects/react-redux-starter-kit/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:60:69)
  at Compilation.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/xxx/WebstormProjects/react-redux-starter-kit/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:563:8)
```

The file I edited is the file that was not found (main.js) but the file exists. I'm sure there are other people with the same problem. Does anyone have a fix?

I'm using the latest Windows Insider Build 14965 with the latest Ubuntu but the problem was also in the previous ones.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Found solution. See under.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a workaround. You have to add:

```
watchOptions: {
  aggregateTimeout: 300,
  poll: 1000
}
```

To your webpack-dev-server because currently WSL doesn't support listening for those events. This works also for Ruby and others but with another config.

See [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/194#issuecomment-132123282).

I think Microsoft will fix this some day.

Comment: I am using Ionic2, so don't have a webpack-dev-server.

Answer (score 0):

For me using Ionic 2 the above error was caused due to a case sensitivity issue on the imports.

In my example, I was doing the following:

```
import { MapRangeModel } from '../model/maprangeModel';
```

when it should have rather been:

```
import { MapRangeModel } from '../model/mapRangeModel';
```